# Adding sheets to an existing Excel File via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

i'm working with a gui in Python, which i created via tkinter.
Now i want to save some data(that i stored in a two dimensional List) in an excel file.
I'm trying to do that in one function.

Here is the Code that i use

```
    def Convert(self):

        list_data_conv = self.list_data

        df=pd.DataFrame(list_data_conv)

        excel_file = '{0}.xlsx'.format(self.Entry_ExcelName.get())
        
        if (self.excel_file_old==excel_file):
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl')
        
        else:
            writer  = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

        self.excel_file_old=excel_file

        sheet_name = '{0}'.format(self.Entry_SheetName.get())

       

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

        writer.save()
```

Using this code, everything works fine except that it still overwrites the Existing Sheet in the Excel File.

Is there a simple fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExcelWriter's default mode is "write", in order to append to it, set mode to append ('a').

Just replace it with :

```
writer  = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```

If the code line above didn't work, try:

```
writer  = pd.ExcelWriter(r'excel_file', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```

**Sould work now**.

Comment: I thin using the "if_sheet_exists" attribute in the ExcelWriter also works.
pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists=‘new’)

Comment: @Oivalf , I think so, but I tried it before with 'repalce' instead of 'new' and it keeps creating new excel sheet, so here I tried to avoid it :P

Comment: @Nova Merci, it works :)